# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Framework_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php When creating User Roles

Tags: helper, data

I encountered a "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Framework_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/latest/app/Mage.php on line 547" when I clicked on create user roles.

Please I need your help on how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the solution to my problem. I renamed the file in app/code/local/Megnor/Framework/etc/adminhtml.xml to admin.xml and it works now. This thread on magentocommerce helped me out http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/354259/.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**adminhtml.xml** or **system.xml** could contain such line(s)

```
<xmlnode translate="title" module="module">
... 
</xmlnode>
```

Magento passes the **module** argument to the Mage::helper() factory method.

```
Mage::helper('module');
```

Factory method looking for the class prefix to use in the node **global/helpers/module/class**. If helper part of config is missing, magento tries to load one from core codepool by prefixing the class id with mage_ and appending _helper.
As a result class prefix = **mage_module_helper** and it resolves to **mage_module_helper_data**. And autoloader tries to load Mage/Module/Helper/Data.php

Comment: Please don't use rude language. If you find other links that you think are spam, just flag them and a moderator will handle them.